# Do not getting value from TextInputLayout when user give input

Tags: java, android, material-design

I'm trying to take some user input using material design like height, weight, age and gender information. When a user click in seeDietChart button, system will calculation and show bmi and bmr. When i give input to textInputLayout, The app is running but not getting any value rather the field stays blank. Here is `xml` file

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:hint="Enter your height in meter"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:hint="Enter your weight in kg"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/age"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:hint="Enter your age"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/gender"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:hint="Your gender"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

After giving input, the variable stays blank. I tried to print the taken value using **Log.i** and **Toast** message. The toast msg is blank. Here is the `java` code

```
    txtHeight = findViewById(R.id.height);
    heightString = txtHeight.getEditText().getText().toString();

    txtWeight = findViewById(R.id.weight);
    weightString = txtWeight.getEditText().getText().toString();

    txtAge = findViewById(R.id.age);
    ageString = txtAge.getEditText().getText().toString();

    txtGender = findViewById(R.id.gender);
    gender = Objects.requireNonNull(txtGender.getEditText()).getText().toString();

    Log.i("Height", heightString);
    Log.i("Weight", weightString);
    Log.i("Age", ageString);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), heightString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**How can i solve this problem?**

Comment: your view ids are `txtGender`, `txtHeight` and so on. Are you not getting an NPE?

Comment: I got an error. Now i updated the view ids.

Comment: Hey you have to set id on TextInputEditText and use it to set it to a variable in Java(findViewById). It is not the variable name in java that matter. What matters is the id in xml is used in R.id.name_of_id.

Comment: One TextInputLayout is holding one TextInputEditText . I set id on every TextInputLayout. I just updated the xml. Would you please check and let me know if it is okay?

Comment: @JahidHasan instead try adding the ids to `edittext` and use it directly?

Comment: I tried. If editText works, then obviously textInputLaout will work.

Answer (score 0):

When the code runs, initially the text Fields are empty. That's why it's not getting any value. To get the value, we need to use a **button** and use **textBox.getText()** method inside the button. It works perfectly fine.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String value = txtHeight.getText().toString();
            }
        });
```